# Data set for identifying columns as categorical or numerical

Tags: data-request, metadata

In a given dataset, a column of numbers can represent a categorical or numerical variable. While one can imagine some simple heuristics for guessing which (e.g., it's categorical if the number of unique values is less than some fixed threshold), I think it would be a fun exercise to train a classifier instead. Features to pass to the classifier might include the number of unique values and the total number of values.

The only difficulty is that I need a labeled data set of such features. It's probably too much to expect that such a meta-dataset already exists, so my question is: are there open data repositories that are sufficiently *uniformly structured* that I could pull the datasets and assemble the features in an *automated* way?

Comment: Can you provide examples of when numbers represent a category versus a variable? I guess I see a flaw with calculating percentages of distinct values as they could be categories or variables depending on the context of the column. It seems only a data dictionary could definitively explain what the column data is representing.

Comment: You're exactly right, which is why I find the problem interesting. My idea is to use ML to find a heuristic smarter than a hard percentage threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a useful resource for this project, the [readMLData](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/readMLData/) R package. It provides a uniform R interface to the UCI Machine Learning Repository. Crucially, it includes copious metadata for each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. *Existing functionality:* The two main open data portal software platforms I have worked with, Socrata and CKAN, have this functionality built in. Socrata is closed source while CKAN is open source.

   - The add-on part of CKAN that handles this is called DataPusher (https://github.com/ckan/datapusher) and it "pushes" data from readable files like CSV to the DataStore extension. Documentation at http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/. The code related to choosing column types is at https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/blob/6175c69e9ab7013272949e6e604fc45d21fce853/datapusher/jobs.py#L282 which uses the messytables python library which can be found at http://messytables.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
2. Check out data.gov, datahub.io, and others for a lot of open data to "train" from. Notably:

   - For Socrata API endpoints, such as `https://open.whitehouse.gov/Government/2010-Report-to-Congress-on-White-House-Staff/rcp4-3y7g` you can get column metadata at URLs such as `https://open.whitehouse.gov/views/rcp4-3y7g/columns.json`. Be careful though, this is no longer documented on dev.socrata.com from what I can tell and might be deprecated/unsupported
   - For CKAN, you need to find the resource ID of a *datastore-backed* resource, and you can create a URL such as `http://54.204.10.90/api/3/action/datastore_search?id=7c0608e3-fb4d-4fb3-928c-5351e5b9b122` and it will show you the metadata of the columns as well

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I haven't looked into (2) very carefully yet, but regarding (1): the column type inference in messytables is for determining the appropriate *storage* format (e.g., string, integer, float). My problem is a bit less trivial: is a given list of integers *semantically* categorial or numerical? In general, it is impossible to know, but there are probably some very good heuristics.

Comment: Ah - I see. That is interesting and is probably more of a statistics question, IMHO, than an open data one. I would assume most numbers are numerical unless otherwise noted.